# Tracking the unique visitors on a page using php

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I know there are many ways to do this.
But I am considering here two methods-

First-
When a user visits a page create a cookie and when a user visits a page check cookie if it is already set or not.

Second-

I would like to store IPs. But suppose if there are 10000 unique visits on a web page, then I need to create a table and store them in it.

Now if I need to check for 100 pages then I need to store 10000 records in hundred tables.
It looked very complicated to me.

So basically I am trying to ask:

1. How many entries I can store in one table?
2. How many tables I can have on my server (say Godaddy) ?
3. I am using many database entries on my site , so if there are too many concurrent users on a site, would it create some problems?

So after considering all possibilities which method is better?

Comment: Why not use a service like Analytics that does this for you, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I agree with Jon Stirling. Further storing IPs is not that reliable, because most user IPs change and therefor are no good identification for this purpose. About a couple of thousand data blocks you do not need to worry. Databases can store insane amounts of information, especially text based information

Comment: (1) Creating hundreds of tables to store the same information is probably bad database design. (2) MySQL is designed to store large volumes of data. Millions of entries in a table are actually a typical use-case and not too extreme. (3) People on the train browsing on mobile will probably change IP every 3-4 minutes. Overall, either use analytics as @JonStirling suggests or use your own tracking cookie technique.

Comment: But using Analytics I can know the stats of site but can I display on my site?
I am trying to sort the web pages according to views. Analytics will do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unusual way to do it with Client-Side databases using [a neat little tool I wrote](https://github.com/Pamblam).

The idea is that you keep your records on the client side rather than creating a database on the server. You can then post it back to the server with ajax if you want.

```
// Load up jSQL library && data
jSQL.load(function(){

    // Create a database if it doesn't exist
    if(undefined === jSQL.tables.visits){
        jSQL.createTable("visits", ['Page', 'ArrivedAt', 'StayedFor'], []);
    }

    // Get the loaded time
    var ArrivedAt = Date.now();

    // Insert a record before the page is unloaded
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        var Page = ""+window.location; // The page being loaded
        var StayedFor = Date.now() - ArrivedAt + "ms"; // How long was the user on the page?
        // Save the data to the database
        jSQL.tables.visits.insertRow({
            Page:Page, 
            ArrivedAt:ArrivedAt, 
            StayedFor:StayedFor
        });
        // Save the data to the database
        jSQL.persist();
    };

    // Has this person visited before?
    var returningVisitor = !!jSQL.tables.visits.data.length;
    if(!returningVisitor){
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "No data yet, leave and come back";
    }else{
        // If the user has been here before, print a table to display records from the databsae
        var visitData = jSQL.query("SELECT * FROM visits").execute().fetchAll();
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = makeTable(visitData);
    } 
});
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/bx2L5L93/

Comment: But how to use it? Can you please provide steps to apply this.

Comment: i gave you instruction in the comments.. download the library file from the link above and copy the code.. let me know if you have a specific problem//